# google authentication in rhomobile

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes

I am new to rhomobile and i am trying to develop an application where i need to authenticate  google account ids for accessing the application.

I have tried using openid for authentication. I have first written a get request to get the XRDS. After getting the XRDS, then i have written a POST request to request the login.

But after sending the post i got a reponse as below:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Method Not Allowed</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR='#FFFFFF' TEXT='#000000'>
<H1>Method Not Allowed</H1>
<H2>Error 405</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>

Params: {"rho_callback"=>"1", "status"=>"error", "error_code"=>"2",            "http_error"=>"405", "headers"=>{"allow"=>"GET, HEAD",
```

"cache-control"=>"private, max-age=0", "content-type"=>"text/html; charset=UTF-8", "date"=>"Mon, 28 May 2012 21:54:15 GMT", "expires"=>"Mon, 28 May 2012 21:54:15 GMT", "server"=>"GSE", "transfer-encoding"=>"chunked", "x-content-type-options"=>"nosniff", "x-frame-options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "x-xss-protection"=>"1; mode=block"}, "__rho_object"=>{"body"=>"0"}, "post"=>"complete"}

Can anyone please help me how to proceed. Or is there some other kind of authentication that i can use?

Answer (score 0):

here some example code of Writing the RhoSync Authentication Method for Google API. This may help you. http://docs.rhomobile.com/google-api-rhodes-rhosync-tutorial#writing-the-rhosync-authentication-method-for-google-api